# Rails devise custom authentication give error undefined method `valid_password?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authentication in the rails application, I need to check password with custom and I used for this

```
 def login
    @email = params[:email]
    @pass = params[:pass]
    @doctor = Doctor.find_by_email(@email).valid_password?(@pass)  
    respond_with(@doctor)
  end
```

But I am getting below error.

```
undefined method `valid_password?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: The email entered by user is invalid and doesn't exist in database. This is what it seems looking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one it will work for you

```
def login
    @email = params[:email]
    @pass = params[:pass]
    @doctor = Doctor.find_by_email(@email)
    if @doctor.nil?
      respond_with('User not available')
    else
      if(@doctor.valid_password?(@pass))
       respond_with(@doctor)
      else
        respond_with('wrong password')
      end  
   end
end
```